# Get a java.lang.NullPointerException while creating Hibernate XML Mapping file

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss, mapping

I'm a begginer with hibernate. I started a Java project on Eclipse and tried to use Hibernate.

First I created my Java classes and my database on MySQL (actually it's empty but not sure there is a link with my issue).

Then I did an import of the hibernate's libraries. I also imported the mysql's connector mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar (I don't really know if I had to do this).

I also added JBoss Tools which allowed me to create all Hibernate conf files.

Then I created my hibernate.cfg.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/match_simulator</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The user and password are not empty in my project ;)

And finally I tried to create a Hibernate XML mapping file but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, and I don't know why. I just can detailed how I did it with pictures

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzOHV.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EkrN.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5AZX.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33oGk.png)

I'm using last version of Eclipse (2020-09 I guess), Hibernate and JBoss Tools.

If it also can help you, I get an error whe I try to test my connection. Here it's the code to test

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        session.close();

    }

}
```

And here is the errors I get

```
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:21 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService <init>
INFO: HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/match_simulator]
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at metier.Test.main(Test.java:13)

déc. 11, 2020 12:01:23 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 01S00
déc. 11, 2020 12:01:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at metier.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:134)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2186)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2209)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1318)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Without further details it's hard to give an answer. A NPE (`NullPointerException`) can occur almost anywhere, so a stack trace is necessary to see where it is happening.

Are you deploying to an application server or developing a Java SE application? If you just want to try out stuff, here is a tutorial: https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/hibernate.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But I don't have more details to give. The `NullPointerException` happened at the end of the wizard. I will add more details on my previous post, can't add a picture here.

I'm developping a Java SE application. If it can help you, I also have an error when I try to test my connection. Actually i set this on `hibernate.connection.url` : `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/match_simulator` but on Squirrel (that I use to query my database) I have to add `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC` at the url connection.

Comment: Just edited my post. If it can help you I also added my code to test the connection with the database that gave me an error. I think it's because of the `hibernate.connection.url`
If I put `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/match_simulator` I get the error as above but if I put `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/match_simulator?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC` it's another error...I'm a little bit lost I think ^^

Comment: You see the error, right? `The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.` Just update the server time zone on your MySQL database to UTC.